# how to convert a tag id into a polymer property?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I’m new with polymer and web developmet.  I’ve started an app in Polymer2.0 and I stuck with this:

1- Into `guiame-app` element I’ve put the `iron-pages`:

```
<iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="inicio" role="main">
     <guiame-inicio name="inicio"></guiame-inicio>
     <guiame-busq name="busqueda"></guiame-busq>
     <guiame-favs name="favs"></guiame-favs>
     <guiame-item name="item"></guiame-item>
     <guiame-g404 name="g404"></guiame-g404>
</iron-pages>
```

2- Into`guiame-inicio` element there’s a list of quick access emergencie phones

```
    <div class="card">
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Bomberos">
          <iron-icon id="bomb" icon="guiaIcons:whatshot" item-icon></iron-icon> Bomberos</paper-icon-item></a>
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Farmacias">
        <iron-icon id="farm" icon="guiaIcons:local-hospital" item-icon> </iron-icon> Farmacias</paper-icon-item></a>
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Policia">
        <iron-icon id="poli" icon="guiaIcons:local-taxi" item-icon> </iron-icon> Policia</paper-icon-item></a>
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Hospital">
        <iron-icon id="hosp" icon="guiaIcons:local-pharmacy" item-icon> </iron-icon> Hospital</paper-icon-item></a>
      <paper-icon-item>
        <a href="item" id="Estado">
        <iron-icon id="est" icon="guiaIcons:location-city" item-icon> </iron-icon> Org. Estatales</paper-icon-item></a>
    </div>
```

3- And finally `guiame-item` with a detailed view of all the needed data. That element retrieves that data from an `iron-ajax` and it most display only the data of the clicked `paper-item` in `guiame-inicio` element:

```
<dom-module id="guiame-item">
    <template >
        <style>
         :host {
            display: block;
            padding: 16px;
        }
    </style>

    <iron-ajax auto url="../assets/emer.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
        <iron-image src="[[item.imagen]]" sizing="cover" alt="[[item.imgAlt]]"></iron-image>
        <h1>[[item.nomb]]</h1>
        <paper-item>Dirección: [[item.dire]]</paper-item>
<!--itera por todos las ocurrencias del array tel -->
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.tel]]">
            <paper-button raised>
                <iron-icon icon="guiaIcons:phone"></iron-icon>[[item]]</paper-button>
            <p></p> 
        </template>
    </template>
</template>

<script>
    class guiameItem extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'guiame-item';
        }
        static get properties() {
            return {
                id: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                },
            };
        }
    }
        customElements.define(guiameItem.is, guiameItem);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

How do I make the `<a>` or `<paper-item>` id in `guiame-inicio` become a property of the `guiame-item` element and filter the response to have only the object information related to the clicked item, from the JSON file?

Thanks in advance, and sorry about my english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `a` tags format looks not correct wrapped. I prefer to remove `a` tags. And add a on-tap="handleButtons" functions into

Your code may look like : `guiame-inicio`

```
   <div class="card">
  <paper-menu-button>
    <paper-button id="bomb"  on-tap = "handleButtons"  item-icon>
        <iron-icon icon="guiaIcons:whatshot"></iron-icon> Bomberos
    </paper-button>

    <paper-button  id="farm"  on-tap = "handleButtons"  item-icon> 
        <iron-icon icon="guiaIcons:local-hospital"></iron-icon> Farmacias
    </paper-button> 

    <paper-button id="poli" on-tap = "handleButtons" item-icon>
        <iron-icon  icon="guiaIcons:local-taxi"></iron-icon> Taxi
    </paper-button>

    <paper-button id="hosp" on-tap = "handleButtons"  item-icon>
       <iron-icon  icon="guiaIcons:local-pharmacy"></iron-icon> Hospital 
    </paper-button> 
    <paper-button id="est"  on-tap = "handleButtons"  item-icon>
        <iron-icon  icon="guiaIcons:location-city"></iron-icon> Org. Estatales
    </paper-button>  
  </paper-menu-button>

</div>
```

...

and function to define which button is pressed : `guiame-inicio`

```
  handleButtons(e) {
             console.info(e.path[0].id);  // will return "bomb" or"farm" ...
             // this.buttonSelected= e.path[0].id; Instead fire event to change page also.
             this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('button-selected', {detail: {button:  e.path[0].id}}));
         }
```

And finally bind this result to dom-repeat as (I assuming you have a category property for phone numbers): `guiame-item`

```
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.tel]]" filter="{{_filterResult(item.category, buttonSelected)}}">
            <paper-button raised>
                <iron-icon icon="guiaIcons:phone"></iron-icon>[[item]]</paper-button>
            <p></p> 
        </template>
```

And filtering function may : `guiame-item`

```
_filterResult(category, filter) {
    if (category != filter) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

I did not able to test but I guess this may give a idea. You may check material design s icon sets : https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-icons/demo/demo/index.html
Also need to bind `buttonSelected` properties between your custom elements as:`guiame-app`

```
<iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="inicio" role="main">
     <guiame-inicio name="inicio" on-button-selected="setPageToNavigate"></guiame-inicio>
     <guiame-busq name="busqueda"></guiame-busq>
     <guiame-favs name="favs"></guiame-favs>
     <guiame-item name="item"  buttonSelected="[[buttonSelected]]"></guiame-item>
     <guiame-g404 name="g404"></guiame-g404>
</iron-pages>


setPageToNavigate(btn) {
    this.set('buttonSelected', btn.detail.button); // this button property dispatched from guiame-inicio  !!
    this.set('page', 'item');
}
```

Also define `buttonSelected` property in `guiame-app` to able to pass into `guiame-item` element

Comment: Excelent aproach @hakanc, but I can't make that the "guiame-item" loads with the filtered data. I don't know if the handleButtons function needs to change the route or I missed something

Comment: I edited the codes above. 1. added an event in 'guiame-inicio' : this will fire an event in guiame-app, to change the page. And defined buttonSelected property in guiame-app, which you can pass. Again, I have not chance to test this. But think it works with fine adjustment.

Comment: Thanks @hakanc I'm still fighting with this. The problem is with the filter. I tried several variants but I realized that the buttonSelected is = 0 and the item.category is = to object when arrived to 'guiame-item'. The handleButton function and the event fired are ok. So I will accept this answer and eventually put another one for the filter. THANKS !!